# Using a ComboBox DropDownList to enumerate COM ports keeps losing current selection in the DropDown event due to clear()

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

There is a function that automatically renews the serialPort in the DropDown event. That's why we periodically clear() it. First {COM1, COM2, COM3}, then {COM1, COM2} when disconnected, maybe {COM1, COM2, COM3} when reconnected.

The problem is disappear that a previously selected value whenever an event occurs. Someone points out that it is because of the use of `clear()`. But, it doesn't occur this problem when `DropDownStyle` is `DropDown`.

I wrote the following code to make the `comboBox1` `ReadOnly`.

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

And, I also have the code like this:

```cs
    private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        // Logic to automatically add items to comboBox1
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

How do I should solve this problem? The key is that it can't input in comboBox other than user selecting value.

Comment: But why do you need to remove the items in the DropDown event?

Comment: @Steve As I wrote in the comments, this is to make sure the item is visible whenever the `DropDown` event fires.

Comment: Did you try to remove all the code in dropdown event. Usually the combobox with dropdownlist style is capable to put the selected item in view

Comment: I'm really trying to understand here, sorry if this example is dumb. So you have a read-only combobox drop down list and 'Orange' is selected from { Orange, Apple, Banana }. What it _sounds_ like is that you want to swap the choices to { Cat, Dog, Hamster } without losing the 'Orange' currently displayed. Tell me  what I'm missing.

Comment: @IVSoftware There is a function that automatically renews the serialPort in the DropDown event. That's why we periodically clear() it. First {COM1, COM2, COM3}, then {COM1, COM2} when disconnected, maybe {COM1, COM2, COM3} when reconnected.

Comment: Thank you that makes much better sense now!

Comment: I've suggested an edit to align the post with the info received in the comments. This should help attract quality answers. You don't have to keep my edits - just roll them back if they don't suit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't make a habit of posting multiple answers on the same thread, but based on your helpful comment, it appears that your "underlying" reason for posting is wanting to keep the `ComboBox` up to date with COM ports that are currently connected.

There might be a more optimal solution to the thing you were trying to do in the first place (this is known as an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)). In my old job I used to do serial port and USB enumeration quite a bit. One trick I learned along the way is that WinOS is going to post a message `WM_DEVICECHANGE` whenever a physical event occurs, things like plugging in or disconnecting a USB serial port device.

In a WinForms app, it's straightforward to detect it by overriding `WndProc`:

```
public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if(m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE) 
    {
        onDeviceChange();
    }
}
```

---

**BindingList**

I would still advocate for assigning the `DataSource` property of the combo box to a `BindingList<ComPort>` where `ComPort` is a class we design to represent the connection info:

```
class ComPort
{
    public string? PortName { get; set; }
    public string? FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public string? PnpDeviceId { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => PortName ?? "None";
    public string GetFullDescription()
    {
        var builder = new List<string>();
        builder.Add($"{PortName}");
        builder.Add($"{FriendlyName}");
        builder.Add($"{nameof(PnpDeviceId)}: ");
        builder.Add($"{PnpDeviceId}");
        return $"{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, builder)}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}";
    }
}
```

---

**Enumeration**

There's a little extra work this way but the enumeration yields a descriptor with additional useful information:

[image: screenshot]

```
    BindingList<ComPort> ComPorts = new BindingList<ComPort>();

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        comboBoxCom.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        comboBoxCom.DropDownClosed += (sender, e) => ActiveControl = null;
        comboBoxCom.DataSource = ComPorts;
        ComPorts.ListChanged += onComPortChanged;
        enumerateComPorts();
    }
    bool _isDeviceChange = false;

    private void onComPortChanged(object? sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_isDeviceChange) BeginInvoke(() => richTextBox.Clear());
        ComPort comPort;
        switch (e.ListChangedType)
        {
            case ListChangedType.ItemAdded:
                comPort = ComPorts[e.NewIndex];
                using (ManagementClass manager = new ManagementClass("Win32_PnPEntity"))
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject record in manager.GetInstances())
                    {
                        var pnpDeviceId = record.GetPropertyValue("PnpDeviceID")?.ToString();
                        if (pnpDeviceId != null)
                        {
                            var subkey = Path.Combine("System", "CurrentControlSet", "Enum", pnpDeviceId, "Device Parameters");
                            var regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkey);
                            if (regKey != null)
                            {
                                var names = regKey.GetValueNames();
                                if (names.Contains("PortName"))
                                {
                                    var portName = regKey.GetValue("PortName");
                                    if (Equals(comPort.PortName, portName))
                                    {
                                        var subkeyParent = Path.Combine("System", "CurrentControlSet", "Enum", pnpDeviceId);
                                        var regKeyParent = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkeyParent);
                                        comPort.FriendlyName = $"{regKeyParent?.GetValue("FriendlyName")}";
                                        comPort.PnpDeviceId = pnpDeviceId;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case ListChangedType.ItemDeleted:
                comPort = _removedItem!;
                break;
            default: return;
        }
        BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (_isDeviceChange) 
            {
                richTextBox.SelectionColor =
                     e.ListChangedType.Equals(ListChangedType.ItemAdded) ?
                     Color.Green : Color.Red;
                richTextBox.AppendText($"{e.ListChangedType}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                richTextBox.AppendText($"Detected{Environment.NewLine}");
            }
            richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(0x20, 0x20, 0x20);
            richTextBox.AppendText(comPort?.GetFullDescription());
        });
    }

    int _wdtCount = 0;
    private ComPort? _removedItem = null;

    private void onDeviceChange()
    {
        _isDeviceChange = true;
        int captureCount = ++_wdtCount;
        Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .GetAwaiter()
            .OnCompleted(() =>
            {
                if(captureCount.Equals(_wdtCount))
                {
                    // The events have settled out
                    enumerateComPorts();
                }
            });
    }
    private void enumerateComPorts()
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        foreach (var port in ports)
        {
            if (!ComPorts.Any(_ => Equals(_.PortName, port)))
            {
                ComPorts.Add(new ComPort { PortName = port });
            }
        }
        foreach (var port in ComPorts.ToArray())
        {
            if (!ports.Contains(port.PortName))
            {
                _removedItem = port;
                ComPorts.Remove(port);
            }
        }
        BeginInvoke(()=> ActiveControl = null); // Remove focus rectangle
    }
```

The `DropDown` event of the combo box is now no longer required. Problem solved!

Comment: [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/combo-box-enumerate-com-ports.git)

Comment: In the future, when I write a post, I'm going to also write down the reason why I need the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to using `Clear`.

One solution is to have a binding list that is the data source of your ComboBox. When you enumerate the available COM ports (shown below as a simulation) you will add or remove com ports from the binding source based on availability. This should result in the behavior you want, because if a com port is "still" available the selection won't change.

[image: screenshot]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBoxCom.DropDownStyle= ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        comboBoxCom.DataSource = MockDataSource;
        refreshAvailableComPorts(init: true);
        comboBoxCom.DropDown += onComboBoxComDropDown;
    }
    BindingList<string> MockDataSource = new BindingList<string>();

    private void onComboBoxComDropDown(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refreshAvailableComPorts(init: false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is a simulation that will choose a different
    /// set of "available" ports on each drop down.
    /// </summary>
    private void refreshAvailableComPorts(bool init)
    {
        if(init) 
        {
            MockDataSource.Clear();
            MockDataSource.Add("COM2");
        }
        else
        {
            string 
                selB4 = string.Join(",", MockDataSource),
                selFtr;
            do
            {
                var flags = _rando.Next(1, 0x10);
                if ((flags & 0x1) == 0) MockDataSource.Remove("COM1");
                else if(!MockDataSource.Contains("COM1")) MockDataSource.Add("COM1");
                if ((flags & 0x2) == 0) MockDataSource.Remove("COM2");
                else if (!MockDataSource.Contains("COM2")) MockDataSource.Add("COM2");
                if ((flags & 0x4) == 0) MockDataSource.Remove("COM3");
                else if (!MockDataSource.Contains("COM3")) MockDataSource.Add("COM3");
                if ((flags & 0x8) == 0) MockDataSource.Remove("COM4");
                else if (!MockDataSource.Contains("COM4")) MockDataSource.Add("COM4");
                selFtr = string.Join(",", MockDataSource);
                if (!selFtr.Equals(selB4))
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (true); 
        }
    }
    private Random _rando = new Random(5);
}
```